# Updating attributes of multiple input controls based on input value using Jquery LINQ

Tags: jquery, linq

Need to update attribute of Input as its Value.

```
Enumerable.From(jQuery(".jQGrid #amount :input").filter('[OrgVal!=value]')).Do(function (x) {
                //OrgVal
                x = jQuery(x);
                var NewValue = x.val();
                x.attr("OrgVal", NewValue);
                }).Force();
```

Condition '[OrgVal!=value]' in filter is to check if OrgVal attribute is not same as the Value in textBox/input.

I have also tried something similar to below.

```
.filter('[OrgVal!=' + value + ']') and     .filter('[OrgVal!=' + val() + ']')
```

We need to filter the Input Controls whose value and orgVal is not same.

We can also do as below without using filter, but it slow down things for more no of rows in loop.`Enumerable.From(jQuery(".jQGrid #amount :input")).Do(function (x) {
                x = jQuery(x);
                var NewValue = x.val();
if (x.attr("OrgVal")!=NewValue){
                x.attr("OrgVal", NewValue);}
                }).Force();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was my mistake, actually my selector was wrong.

```
jQuery("#jQGrid .amount").filter('[OrgVal!=value]')
```

is working